# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2549).

Answer (score 55):

[image: Dennis Ritchie Home Page]

Comment: Looks like dmr's shirt has some aliasing going on. Maybe this one could be replaced with a version that's been properly resized if it gets used?

Comment: Here's another version with the same cropping. It's slightly dimmer, but I think the shirt looks better in this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wipgc.png

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger Sorry about that. The image is fixed now ([old](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kJwwT.png) vs. [new](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nbgEl.png)).

Comment: Ah, that looks great!

Answer (score 41):

[image: vim's rebirth for the 21st century]

Answer (score 39):

[image: Zsh: the last word in Unix shells]

Comment: I see what you did there :D

Comment: @JosephR. I don't see it; could you explain, please?

Comment: @NewWorld Try this: `grep -oP '\w+' /etc/shells | tail -1`

Comment: @NewWorld, yes, that's inspired from _ZFS: the last word in filesystems_. The image itself is stolen from http://zshwiki.org

Answer (score 37):

[image: GNU's Not Unix!]

Answer (score 36):

[image: The universal operating system]

Answer (score 33):

[image: Arch Linux: A simple, lightweight Linux distribution.]

Answer (score 29):

[image: Question closing feed]

Answer (score 27):

[image: Docker: the Linux container engine]

Comment: Background: [SO: Powerful functionalities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989306/what-does-docker-add-to-just-plain-lxc) And [Docker 0.7 runs on all Linux distributions](http://blog.docker.io/2013/11/docker-0-7-docker-now-runs-on-any-linux-distribution/)

Answer (score 24):

[image: Ken Thompson]

Comment: please find another picture... this one is scary

Comment: I saw this in the sidebar and expected an obituary.

Answer (score 23):

[image: GNU Image Manipulation Program]

Answer (score 22):

[image: FreeBSD]

Answer (score 21):

[image: GNU Emacs]

Answer (score 21):

[image: qemu: OpenSource Virtualisation]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Freedom. Friends. Features. First.]

Answer (score 14):

[image: A keyboard-driven, minimalist web browser]

Comment: It's a pity it's not clear from the picture what kind of project this is. Just out of random curiosity, I clicked the link and liked a lot to learn about the project. But what about other who have no reason to cleick because of the picture?

Answer (score 14):

[image: Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) is a semi-rolling distribution based on Debian Testing.]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Perl]

Comment: It's the first time in 15 years of using `perl` that I come across (or notice I suppose) this logo. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Onion_symbol) that's referring to _pearl onions_. Not so good an image given that it only works in english (German as well?), and even then, I don't see the point really. Possible confusion with TOR as well.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas This happens to be the logo used by [The Perl Foundation](http://www.perlfoundation.org/). Also, Larry Wall's Perl talks are called "State of the Onion". The Camel was popularized by the O'Reilly books. I put this image instead of the Camel intentionally hoping its lack of widespread recognition will prompt people to click through (hey, it caught your attention, didn't it?) :)
I do agree on the potential confusion with TOR, though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The pun _does_ seem to work better in German, where a pearl onion is known as a _[Perlzwiebel](https://www.google.com/search?%7Bgoogle:acceptedSuggestion%7Doq=pearl+onion+in+german&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pearl+onion+in+german)_ :)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : I think this is a pretty common association -- [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) has been using it for years too...although that web interface is really the work of a particular individual who may or may not be associated with the Foundation.  Be happy it's not [Duke](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/duke-424174.html)...

Comment: I though it was TOR O_O

Answer (score 11):

[image: Slackware]

Comment: SMOKING IS BAD FOR YOU *(apparently)* - though it doesn't show any smoke... +1

Comment: @Wilf It's probably one of those pipes that produces soap bubbles.

Comment: a mix of tux and the church of the SubGenius? praise Bob!

Answer (score 11):

[image: FreeDesktop.org]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Haiku OS]

Comment: Interesting. Does it offer its own implementation of POSIX utilities or does it rely on an existing one?

Comment: @JosephR. no idea, I only know about it from an [XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/806/) but it sounds cool and is open and *nix(ish) so we may as well promote it :).

Comment: Hahahahaha. Great comic!! If only. In all such conversations I make a conscious effort to conceal the fact that I'm running *nix because you know they'll directly jump to blaming the problem on that.

Comment: @JosephR. I've found a trick, when I call my ISP tech support, I ask them things like "Do you know what ssh, telnet, ftp or ping are? No. OK, please let me speak to someone who does". That tends to speed things up wonderfully until I am talking to someone who knows more than I do and can actually help.

Comment: Nice. Kind of a reverse Shibboleth, if you will :D

Comment: @terdon does that actually work? if that wasn't a joke, you are my hero.

Comment: @strugee often it does, yes. It kinda freaks them out and they pass you on to the next poor schmuck down the line until you hit an actual engineer who can help.

Comment: Definitly not a product with future, no offence for developers but an OS that start supporting 32bits only without relying on existing basis is lead to stay a very marginal product used only by there developers. that's only my personnal opinion but starting an OS now with the whole diversity and complexity of hardware (compare to the 90's) is a nice but fullish dream. (see reactOS... react what ?)

Comment: @Kiwy sorry but you completely misunderstood what this is. 1) Haiku is a continuation of BeOS which started in 1991 (though they have not kept much code) 2) it has not yet reached a stable release and they're working on 64 bit. Starting small makes sense. Anything that brings something like BeOS back into the game has my vote.

Answer (score 10):

[Tagline to show on mouseover http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/unix.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: There's server-side magic that detects the referrer and serve the proper image and it's updated in "semi-real-time". [See the original for more information](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884/63289), specifically [this comment](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/932/community-promotion-ads-2012/998#comment2449_998)

Comment: This violates 2 of the requirements. 1) "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels". 2) "Must be hosted through our standard image uploader"

Comment: @Patrick check [Apple's](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884/63289) and [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8593/169736) advertisement. [It does work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dKAN0.png)

Comment: So 'the rules are more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules'?

Comment: @Patrick obviously this add has been for a long while in SE and the SE team hasn't said anything against it.

Comment: The fact that it's hosted by S.E. as a "dynamic ad" -- http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png -- implies it's either created or endorsed by them, I think.  *Someone* at least pulled some strings or plead the case to make this happen. +1 !!!

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Actually, the ad is neither created nor explicitly endorsed by Stack Exchange. The URL is as such because that app name was available on Heroku, so Jason and I picked it. However, by now I'd say that the ad has SE's implicit approval as it's existed for over 2 years on Ask Different without them removing it or objecting to it.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Five Things in Fedora This Week. Wow.]

Comment: mattdm [assures us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15651171#15651171) this is a picture of dmr's dog. Although he apparently held the shift key with his eyes while typing that, for some reason. At least I think that's what the next line in the transcript means.

Comment: Wow!  This is the best I've seen!  Such helpful, much updates, many fun!  Even so news!  +1

Answer (score 9):

[image: midnight commander]

Comment: Wow, that is one fugly logo...

Comment: Eye of the beholder I guess. I like the ninja-esqueness, but it's obviously an icon blown up too far. The [one used on the site](https://www.midnight-commander.org/chrome/site/MidnightCommander.png) is no bigger, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

[image: friendly interactive shell]

Comment: I love how the home page begins, *"Finally, a command
line shell for the 90s"*...

Answer (score 8):

[image: nginx — high-performance web-server for accelerated web infrastructure]

Comment: An ad for Nginx will be a good idea. You should improve the design.

Comment: [He didn't design it in the first place.](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3994/33417) But I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Linux Mint: from freedom freedom came elegance]

Comment: There is another [a Linux Mint](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2625/1925) ad option that I think is prettier. Since it's specific to the LMDE edition, maybe this could be revised with something prettier for the main edition. Maybe based on artwork from 17?

Answer (score 6):

[image: systemd]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Five Things in Fedora This Week]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Pipelight allows you to use Windows only plugins in Linux browsers. It supports Silverlight, Unity Webplayer, Shockwave, Flash and more.]

Comment: I'm aware this will probably get downvoted here, but in my opinion it's the best solution if you have to deal with this stuff (well, better than using a browser in Wine or even using a VM). Please tell me if you think this ad could be improved, or download the source file: http://www.pwnicorn.tk/public/AU-Pipelight_xcf

Answer (score 3):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx]

Answer (score 3):

[image: mdoc.su — short manual page URLs, a deterministic URL shortener for BSD manual pages, written in nginx.conf]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Operating systems principles and design — Computer Science Stack Exchange]

Comment: Thanks to [Wandering Logic](https://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/799/advertising-computer-science-stack-exchange-on-other-se-sites/962#962)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ubuntu: Linux for human beings]

Comment: I know that someones miss the good oldfashion logo, but now deal with it it's the ugly http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-logo14.png

Answer (score 1):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine, over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx, it is uber fast and has very short URLs.]

Answer (score 1):

[image: An open-source editor for experienced web designers and programmers, supporting many programming and markup languages, but focusing on creating dynamic and interactive websites.]

Comment: Why the downvote? The GIMP one was mostly copied, but I had to design this...

Comment: Maybe because Bluefish is just another editor, while GIMP is indispensable. Just a hint. I not know Bluefish enough, so I not voted on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions. BSD is Dying. Seeking Kernel and Userland Developers to Hack and Improve BSD UNIX. Qualifications: C (required), asm (a plus). No prior open-source experience necessary. Warning: it's not for the faint of heart!]

Comment: At first glance, this looks like something that will give you a virus if you click it. On the other hand I love how BSD is still said to be "dying" despite the first such proclamation being made ~15 years ago--that's a long death!

Answer (score -1):

[image: Teckids e.V. – Erkunden, Entdecken, Erfinden – Discover, Explore, Forge]

Comment: Too local. Maybe create a portal to several similar projects.

Comment: @Dereckson Sure, with only about 10 people it needs to be (somewhat – we do currently try to be present in many places in Germany already) local. But without any advertising, we cannot grow that much (henn/egg problem). But we’re willing to partner with related projects of course.

Answer (score -9):

[image: /sys/kern/init_main.c::mi_startup() — system startup; initialise the world, create process 0, mount root filesystem and fork to create init and pagedaemon.]

Comment: I fail to see why would someone get interested by this one.

Answer (score -20):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: ..Which clearly nobody does :-p

Comment: @Josh You guys are actually the [second lowest score](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6005/community-promotion-ads-2014/6006#6006) this season. Which is impressive, I'd say.

Comment: @GraceNote well, is there any point in advertising a site _on the site itself_? I'd love to see this as a community add on [su] or [so] but anyone who's here already knows us, so this seems completely pointless. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @terdon Maybe you want your users to know you have a twitter account?

Comment: What benefit does the Twitter account have? I'm genuinely curious, I don't understand it. Why provide another layer of indirection over the top of the site, especially when the signal to noise of the questions highlighted there is typically so poor?

Comment: I'd actually prefer if we didn't have a twitter bot. I find the traffic useless to the site. More eyeballs doesn't equate to better quality visitors.